# How to console.log the http response?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm using the following async await with a get call. If there is an error the server also sends a response, a text-message. The Text-message can be seen in the network-tab. How can I console log that message, as it is not part of the error in the catch-block.

```
callServer = async () => {
    const path = '...';
    try {
      await axios.get(path);
      console.log('successful');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: I think the message should be a property of the error object. Can you set a breakpoint at the console.log line and see what is in the error object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default for axios is:

```
console.log(error.response.data);
```

But it depends on how you've configured axios.

**Tip**
Use `console.dir(error)` to see what is inside the error variable.